# How to use Knowledge Articles for showing contextual help on custom objects?

Tags: lightning, knowledge

I’m trying to find a method of easily displaying related Knowledge articles in the flow of my users work.

The Cases lightning Component is a great example, but I can’t use that component on Custom Objects.  I know that this component is here to help resolve cases.

For me, I want object level help, not record level.  Is there a way to enable this functionality through?  A custom field on the Article where we can select related objects?

I’m trying to build up a method for internal help relying on Articles.  But I’m finding it a bit limiting, given that my users have very limited technical skills.